# Cannot find module typescript.js after Windows restoration point. I'm triying to build my angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I had problems with my PC and I restored windows to and old restoration point.

After this... When I try to build my Angular App I have the next error:

```sh
C:\Udemy\AngularDeCeroAExpertoEdicion2021\03-paisesApp>npm run build

> paises-app@0.0.0 build C:\Udemy\AngularDeCeroAExpertoEdicion2021\03-paisesApp
> npm run config -- --environment=prod && ng build --prod


> paises-app@0.0.0 config C:\Udemy\AngularDeCeroAExpertoEdicion2021\03-paisesApp
> ts-node ./src/assets/scripts/setEnv.ts "--environment=prod"

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:329
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Udemy\AngularDeCeroAExpertoEdicion2021\03-paisesApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:321:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:534:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:98:19)
    at loadCompiler (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:208:34)
    at create (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:213:28)
    at Object.register (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:184:21)
    at main (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:129:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:448:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Udemy\\AngularDeCeroAExpertoEdicion2021\\03-paisesApp\\node_modules\\typescript\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'typescript'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! paises-app@0.0.0 config: `ts-node ./src/assets/scripts/setEnv.ts "--environment=prod"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the paises-app@0.0.0 config script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-01T08_27_09_159Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! paises-app@0.0.0 build: `npm run config -- --environment=prod && ng build --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the paises-app@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-01T08_27_09_186Z-debug.log
```

I think that the problem is with the directory:

`C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\`

What can I do?
remove the folder node_modules?
reinstall npm?

I tried with `npm install` and all is ok.

Thanks.

**Edited:**

Maybe the problem was in my merged branches or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by doing the following:

- Remove the folder **/node_modules** of my Angular App.
- Run `npm install`.
- And then run `npm run build` or `npm run start` or `ng serve`.

I have also found a package that does the same. The package name is **reinstall**

[reinstall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reinstall)

Reinstall package's node modules without cache.

- Removes node_modules directory
- Clean's NPM cache
- Install's modules from package.json

`npm install reinstall -g`

Once installed remember restart your terminal and run `reinstall` in your root dir.

Maybe the problem was in my merged branches or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not specified what was the installed state of apps when the restoration point was lastly set, I presume that you have all the npm packages captured correctly at that point. If so, try doing the below steps...

Since you have not included the entire log with this, I can guess it is possibly an ambiguity issue due to references not properly resolved!

Open command prompt/powershell/terminal, etc. with admin privilege. Do as below (`sudo` command not to be used with `Windows` OS): -

- `sudo npm cache clean --force`
- `sudo npm cache verify`
- Delete the `package-lock.json` file located at `C:\Users\<your_username>`

Try installing your project dependencies now from your project folder with `npm i` or `yarn install` (if you're using `yarn` as your preferred package manager).

Note: - If this doesn't work, follow the same process as above (again) and uninstall `npm`/`yarn` and `node` and reinstall it. It should work then!